# Run a scheduled task if memory usage goes above 90%

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Is it possible on Windows to use task scheduler or other methods to run a script if the memory usage on the device goes above a certain level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell might work well for this.  You could schedule something like this to run every so often to check memory and then run your script.  If you already have a script you just have to add '& PathTo\yourscript.bat' into the if statement.

```
$memory = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername localhost | 
Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N0}” -f 
((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ 
$_.TotalVisibleMemorySize)}} 

$memoryUsage = [int]$memory.MemoryUsage

#if usage over 90% do something
if ($memoryUsage -gt 90){
    echo "script goes here"
}
```